# Read and write to different Mongo collections using Spark with Java

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark

I am a relative newbie to Spark. I need to read from a Mongo collection in Java using Spark, change some field values, let's say I am appending "123" to one field value and write into another collection. Accordingly I had 2 separate Mongo URIs as the input and output URIs configured in Spark. I am then proceeding to read from the input collection. However, what I am not understanding is how would I make the same RDD of documents as output to another collection. This is the input code:

```
String inputUri = "mongodb://" + kp.getProperty("source.mongo.userid") + ":"
                + Encryptor.decrypt(kp.getProperty("source.mongo.cache")) + "@"
                + kp.getProperty("source.mongo.bootstrap-servers") + "/" + kp.getProperty("source.mongo.database")
                + "." + kp.getProperty("source.mongo.inputCollection") + "?ssl=true&connectTimeoutMS="
                + kp.getProperty("source.mongo.connectTimeoutMS") + "&socketTimeoutMS="
                + kp.getProperty("source.mongo.socketTimeoutMS") + "&maxIdleTimeMS="
                + kp.getProperty("source.mongo.maxIdleTimeMS");

String outputUri = "mongodb://" + kp.getProperty("source.mongo.userid") + ":"
                + Encryptor.decrypt(kp.getProperty("source.mongo.cache")) + "@"
                + kp.getProperty("source.mongo.bootstrap-servers") + "/" + kp.getProperty("source.mongo.database")
                + "." + kp.getProperty("source.mongo.outputCollection") + "?ssl=true&connectTimeoutMS="
                + kp.getProperty("source.mongo.connectTimeoutMS") + "&socketTimeoutMS="
                + kp.getProperty("source.mongo.socketTimeoutMS") + "&maxIdleTimeMS="
                + kp.getProperty("source.mongo.maxIdleTimeMS");

SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[3]").appName(kp.getProperty("spark.app.name"))
                     .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", inputUri)
                     .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", outputUri)
                     ...;

JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());

JavaMongoRDD<Document> rdd = MongoSpark.load(sc);

System.out.println("Count: " + rdd.count());
System.out.println(rdd.first().toJson());
```

Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer myself. I went the Dataset route instead of RDDs which made the modification simpler. So, to load the Mongo colection, I use

```
Dataset<Row> df = MongoSpark.load(sc).toDF();
```

Then I create a temporary view upon it in orcder to be able to use Spark SQL:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("Customer");
```

I register an UDF for operating upon each column value:

```
spark.udf().register("Test", new TestUDF(), DataTypes.StringType);
```

the UDF definition is as follows:

```
public class TestUDF implements UDF1<String, String> {

@Override
public String call(String customer) throws Exception {

    return customer + "123";
}

}
```

Then I call the UDF using the same column name as the original so that the values in the original dataset are replaced:

```
df = df.withColumn("CustomerName", functions.callUDF("Test", functions.col("CustomerName")));
```

Then I write it back to Mongo in a separate collection:

```
MongoSpark.write(df).option("collection", "myCollection").save();
```